# Dual monitor setup cuts off "All Programs..." menu on bottom

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, start-menu

I have a dual monitor setup under Win XP SP3 at work, a laptop screen at 1280x800 and a LCD at 1280x1024.  The LCD is set up as the primary monitor because it has more space and is larger, and the Start Bar is on the laptop to further maximize my space.

The problem I have is that whenever I go to Start >> All Programs, the bottom few are chopped off, like the menu wants to be 1024px high on the 800px screen.  I've tried to shrink the amount of programs by putting them into folders, but I keep having to reorganize.  Is there anything I can do to actually fix this problem?

Comment: I've never moved my task bar off my primary monitor, and I bet that wasn't something that got thoroughly tested.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you can fix your problem by moving the other screen so the bottom is aligned rather than the top.  I have *NOT* tested this, though!  (Desktop, right click, settings, move the pictures of the monitor.)

Comment: Doing this in the Intel tool or Windows tool seems to have no effect on this.  I somewhat 'fixed' it by padding it with some junk shortcuts; it took 8 but I only see half of one.

Answer (score 1):

Right click by the Start button, choose Properties, Start menu, Customize, Advanced.  Scroll almost all the way down and put a tick in "Scroll Programs."